# compare 2 arrays and update one to always be identical to the other

Tags: php, sql-server, moodle, moodle-api

I have 2 arrays, one containing values in the database and the other containing currently selected check boxes. I would like to compare both and would like to either update or delete records in the database values list($db_domains) based on the currently selected check boxes list ($page_view_domains). This way the array containing the database values is always dependent on the checked checkboxes list.

```
$db_domains = array($domain->id); 
$page_view_domains = array($form_entry->{"domain_$domain->id"});
$results = array_diff($db_domains, $page_view_domains);
```

I have the difference  stored in the $results variable but don't know what to do with it.

Comment: It is unclear from this question what exactly you're trying to do.  Maybe add some sample data and your expected results

Comment: simply compare 2 arrays and make the values of a specific one ($db_domain) always match the values of the other ($page_view_domains)... to be submitted to the database.

Comment: `$db_domain = $page_view_domains;`

Answer (score 0):

array_diff in this case will give you the values you need to remove, because it's what in the db but absent in the form values. So you just iterate this array and delete values.

array_diff applied backwards `$tocreate = array_diff($page_view_domains, $db_domains);` will give you values you need to create in the database. So you iterate it and create records.

Other records, as far as I understand, should remain unchanged, since they are only ids, not structures